# Difference between Travel and Commute

Tags: vocabulary

So I am taking some english lessons on grammar and vocabulary and the teacher said that there was a difference between the meaning of travelling and commuting. He did explain it but I can't seem to remember it now and even  when I did hear it, couldnt understand it properly. Could someone kindly help me out with this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Commuting** is a special kind of traveling.  You do it regularly in order to get back and forth to school, to your job, or to your family.

Think of a *commuter train*.  Such a train picks passengers up in the morning in the outskirts of the city, has no runs between approximately 10 am and 3 pm, and then starts delivering passengers back to the outskirts again starting around 4 pm.

This is related to the *commutative law of addition* -- *a + b = b + a*.  *a* and *b* trade places!  When you commute to work, you just go back and forth between points A and B, over and over again.  This is a boring kind of traveling.

When someone says, "I like to travel," they are imagining going to A, B, C, D, E -- and this is not boring!

Answer (score -3):

Since this pertains to the 'travel' sense of the words -- because the comparison is between *travel* and *commute* -- I am not looking at the other meaning of the word commute from the legal domain.

So, IMO: 
To **commute** means to travel locally in a city or town.
To **travel** means to go from one city or town to another.
It's as simple as that.

Comment: Welcome to ELU and we appreciate your desire to help. Your answer (irrespective of how correct it may sound), needs to contain reference/citation to appropriate online source(s) which support it. You may want to take the site [tour]. Following the guideline will help your answer get up-votes and otherwise it may be deleted.

Comment: Your definition of *commute* in terms of *travel* isn't wrong, but then conflicts with your definition of *travel* (which is too narrow).